# Changes to [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber not reflected immediately

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using following code to change the Application badge number and badge on tab bar when user reads a message.  I am seeing some unexplainable behavior.  If the method is called when [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber= 1, the applicationIconBadgeNumber is decremented to 0.  But unless I have the sleep(1) between decrement and the next if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber>=1), the if condition evaluates to True and DDLogPrint says "Setting tab bar badge to 0 because appbadge is 0".  if I use the sleep line, then things work as expected (i.e tab bar badge gets set to nil).

Is it expected that changes to [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber can take some time?

```
-(void) decrementBadges
{

 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 UITabBarController *myTabBarController = (UITabBarController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
 UITabBarItem *tbItem = (UITabBarItem *)[myTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:CHAT_TAB_INDEX];

 DDLogVerbose(@"In decrement badges with badge number = %ld, tab bar icon = %@, numMessageRead=%ld",(long)[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber,tbItem.badgeValue, (long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"numMsgRead"]) ;

 if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber>=1)
 {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber-- ;
 }

 //sleep(1) ; //If I uncomment this line, then it works, tab bar badge gets set to nil when method is called with applicationIconBadgeNumber =1
 if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber>=1)
 {
    tbItem.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber];
    DDLogVerbose(@"Setting tab bar badge to %@ because appbadge is %ld",tbItem.badgeValue,(long)[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber) ;
 }
 else
 {
    tbItem.badgeValue = nil;
    DDLogVerbose(@"Setting tab bar badge to nil because appbadge is %ld",(long)[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber) ;
 }
}
```

Comment: Is your `decrementBadges` method being called on a background thread? All of the code you posted needs to be run on the main thread. And *NEVER* use `sleep` on the main thread.

Comment: I am currently running everything on main thread.  I haven't gotten to GCD yet.  Next step after I get all the functional issues ironed out.

Comment: I used the sleep just to see if it will fix it.  I never do it in actual code!